# Boost exceptions not caught when linking to Homebrew libc++

Tags: c++, macos, linker, homebrew, libc++

I am working on MacOS 13, my `clang++` is Homebrew clang version 15.0.6, boost is Homebrew boost 1.81.0.

Consider the following program `test.cpp`:

```cpp
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char** argv){
    namespace bpo = boost::program_options;
    bpo::options_description options("Allowed options");
    options.add_options();
    bpo::variables_map options_vm;
    try {
        bpo::store(bpo::parse_command_line(argc, argv, options), options_vm);
        bpo::notify(options_vm);
    }
    catch(boost::program_options::error &e){
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

Compiling the program with

```
clang++ -isystem /usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lboost_program_options test.cpp
```

works, and calling `./a.out --asdf` correctly reports the mistake and exits as intended.

The libc++ the above links to (I suppose, the system version) seems not to provide support for compiling with `-D_LIBCPP_ENABLE_ASSERTIONS=1`. Therefore, I tried linking to the Homebrew version of libc++ and compiling with

```bash
clang++ -isystem /usr/local/include  -L/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib/c++ -lc++ -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib/c++ -L/usr/local/lib -lboost_program_options test.cpp
```

When running `./a.out --asdf` again, I get `libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type boost::wrapexcept<boost::program_options::unknown_option>`.

What's going on here? Is it because the Homebrew boost is linked to the native libc++, and not the one from Homebrew LLVM? How can I resolve the issue?

**Edit.** One suggestion was to use

```
clang++ --sysroot=/usr/local/opt/llvm -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lboost_program_options test.cpp
```

This results in

```
In file included from test.cpp:2:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/program_options.hpp:15:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/program_options/options_description.hpp:11:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/program_options/config.hpp:10:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/config.hpp:57:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/config/platform/macos.hpp:28:
/usr/local/include/boost/config/detail/posix_features.hpp:18:15: fatal error: 'unistd.h' file not found
#     include <unistd.h>
              ^~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

Comment: I _think_ you should use `--sysroot=/usr/local/opt/llvm` and drop `-isystem ...`, the `-L...`s and `-lc++` to get both headers and libraries from your `/usr/local/opt/llvm` installation.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thank you. That does not solve the issue, though, see my edit.

Comment: It seems the installation in `/usr/local/opt/llvm` is not enough and you still require the local platform's headers. Try adding `-isystem /path/to/dir_with_unistd.h` too

Comment: Not related to your problem, but putting `-lfoo` before `test.cpp` on the link line is likely to cause problems on other systems. You should put all `-lfoo` _after_ all the sources.